# crosstool-ng cant fetch linux tarball

Tags: linux, wget, crosstool-ng

I'm trying to build a tool chain using `crosstool-ng`, I've set it all up, selected my cpu as described on http://crosstool-ng.org/#download_and_usage and I'm at the step where I can build my toolchain. When I enter `ct-ng build` however, it cancels with the following error:

```
$ ct-ng build
[INFO ]  Performing some trivial sanity checks
[INFO ]  Build started 20170126.135517
[INFO ]  Building environment variables
[EXTRA]  Preparing working directories
[EXTRA]  Installing user-supplied crosstool-NG configuration
[EXTRA]  =================================================================
[EXTRA]  Dumping internal crosstool-NG configuration
[EXTRA]    Building a toolchain for:
[EXTRA]      build  = x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
[EXTRA]      host   = x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
[EXTRA]      target = powerpc-e500v2-linux-gnuspe
[EXTRA]  Dumping internal crosstool-NG configuration: done in 0.09s (at 00:02)
[INFO ]  =================================================================
[INFO ]  Retrieving needed toolchain components' tarballs
[EXTRA]    Retrieving 'linux-4.3'
[ERROR]
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Build failed in step 'Retrieving needed toolchain components' tarballs'
[ERROR]  >>        called in step '(top-level)'
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Error happened in: do_kernel_get[scripts/build/kernel/linux.sh@741]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: main[scripts/crosstool-NG.sh@590]
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  For more info on this error, look at the file: 'build.log'
[ERROR]  >>  There is a list of known issues, some with workarounds, in:
[ERROR]  >>      '/usr/local/share/doc/crosstool-ng/crosstool-ng-1.22.0/B - Known issues.txt'
[ERROR]
[ERROR]  (elapsed: 0:31.10)
[00:31] / make: *** [build] Error 1
```

In `build.log` I get the following:

```
[EXTRA]    Retrieving 'linux-4.3'
...
...
...
[DEBUG]    Not at this location: "http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/longterm/v4.3/linux-4.3.zip"
[DEBUG]    Trying 'http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/longterm/linux-4.3.zip'
[DEBUG]    ==> Executing: 'wget' '--passive-ftp' '--tries=3' '-nc' '--...
[DEBUG]    Not at this location: "http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/longterm/linux-4.3"
[ERROR]
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Build failed in step 'Retrieving needed toolchain components' tarballs'
[ERROR]  >>        called in step '(top-level)'
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Error happened in: do_kernel_get[scripts/build/kernel/linux.sh@741]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: main[scripts/crosstool-NG.sh@590]
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  For more info on this error, look at the file: 'build.log'
[ERROR]  >>  There is a list of known issues, some with workarounds, in:
[ERROR]  >>      '/usr/local/share/doc/crosstool-ng/crosstool-ng-1.22.0/B - Known issues.txt'
[ERROR]
[ERROR]  (elapsed: 0:31.10)
```

I understand that it's not able to retrieve the kernel, is there a way I can download it manually and tell the script where the tarball is located?

Okay, I realized that 
`wget http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.3.tar.gz` will fail but `wget --no-check-certificate http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.3.tar.gz` will work to download the tarball just fine through the proxy.
So I copied `/usr/bin/wget` to /usr/binwget~orig`and wrote a wrapper`/usr/bin/wget` that looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/wget~orig --no-check-certificate $1
```

but that doesn't seem to work either, I now get the following in `build.log`:

```
[DEBUG]    ==> Executing: 'wget' '--passive-ftp' '--tries=3' '-nc' '--progress=dot:binary' '-T' '10' '-O' '/home/ron/src/toolchain/work/.build/tarballs/linux-4.3.tar.xz.tmp-dl' 'http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.3.tar.xz'
[ALL  ]    wget~orig: missing URL
[ALL  ]    Usage: wget~orig [OPTION]... [URL]...
[ALL  ]
[ALL  ]    Try `wget~orig --help' for more options.
[DEBUG]    Not at this location: "http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.3.tar.xz"
[DEBUG]    Trying 'http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/longterm/v4.3/linux-4.3.tar.xz'
[DEBUG]    ==> Executing: 'wget' '--passive-ftp' '--tries=3' '-nc' '--progress=dot:binary' '-T' '10' '-O' '/home/ron/src/toolchain/work/.build/tarballs/linux-4.3.tar.xz.tmp-dl' 'http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/longterm/v4.3/linux-4.3.tar.xz'
[ALL  ]    wget~orig: missing URL
[ALL  ]    Usage: wget~orig [OPTION]... [URL]...
```

How does it automagically know that my original `wget` binary is now called `wget~orig`??? Andit tries to use that insteadof my wrapper that's now located at `/usr/bin/wget` (yes, I've added the x permissions and tried it out too, a `wget http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.3.tar.gz` from the shell (utilizing my wrapper script) works just fine now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay,

Since `wget` gets called with muliple (9) arguments, I fixed my wrapper script (at `/usr/bin/wget`)to look like:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/wget~orig --no-check-certificate $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9
```

That seems to be working succesfully to download  the source tarballs required by `ct-ng`

Answer (score 2):

You can configure `ct-ng` to prevent it from downloading sources:

```
ct-ng menuconfig
```

- Go to `Path and misc options`
- In `*** Downloading ***`, select `[*] Forbid downloads`
- Exit...

When you try to build your toolchain (`ct-ng build`) the build process will expect you to put manually downloaded tarballs in `~/src`.

Just inspect `build.log` to know what tarballs are wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure `ct-ng` to pass extra arguments to `wget`:
ct-ng menuconfig

- Go to `Path and misc options`
- In `*** Downloading ***`, under the `Connection timeout` option
- Select `(--passive-ftp --tries=3 -nc --progress=dot:binary...`
- add `--no-check-certificate`
- Exit

This is insecure, however it allows you to forgo creating the wrapper script for wget mentioned in other answers

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with downloading linux (wget failed) and zlib (version 1.2.12 not found). For those 2 a manual download of the tarball was required.

I found that any manually downloaded tarballs need to be placed into
`/.build/tarball`

If you dont have the `/.build` folder trying the following.

`select [*] Forbid downloads`

`ct-ng build` *it will fail*

now the `/.build` should exist

Add tarballs

`deselect [ ] Forbid downloads`

`ct-ng build`